# Prove that a sequence of $11$ numbers always contains six numbers summing up to a multiple of $6$.

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

> Prove that a sequence of $11$ numbers always contains six numbers summing up to a multiple of $6$.

This is a problem from a selection to IMO 2014.

Comment: Look up combinatorial nullstellenstaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Erdos Ginzburg Ziv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGZ_theorem) theorem (namely with $n=6$).

The theorem in general says that if you take $2n-1$ integers, then some subset of size $n$ must have sum that is a multiple of $n$.  You can find several proofs [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16721).