# Count the numbers satisfying division criteria in discrete maths

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a problem in Discrete Math to ask: How many least non-negative numbers are there that we can always take randomly 23 numbers from that set which having sum divisible to 23?

I'm thinking about a set containing all possible remainders when dividing to 23, so the set has 22*23 = 506 numbers.
I dont think it is correct, so can you guys help me. Many thanks

Comment: Why are your thinking avout such a set? Why don't you think it is correct? Can you please edit your post to share more thoughts and efforts? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "we can always take randomly $23$ numbers from that set"?

Comment: @jor, my guess is OP doesn't really mean random, just that there is a subset of $23$ that add to something divisible by $23$. But maybe you knew that, and just wanted to hear it from OP.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017005/given-n-integers-is-it-always-possible-to-choose-m-from-them-so-that-their and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369377/sum-of-n-numbers-divisible-by-n and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807299/prove-that-a-sequence-of-11-numbers-always-contains-six-numbers-summing-up-to

Comment: Have any of those links been helpful, Newbie?